# How to use IF NOT EXISTS condition in Snowflake

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have task to migrate our code from SYNAPSE TO SNOWFLAKE.
One of the SP code of lines starts with IF NOT EXISTS in synapse. I am trying to write same way in snowflake and this causing failures . Could you please help by seeing below line of sample code from synapse and help me how can i transform it into snowflake.

```
CREATE PROC SAMPLE_PROC
AS 
BEGIN
    if not exists (select 'x' from [Schema].[table_name] where SnapshotDate = cast(getdate() as date))
    BEGIN
          set @MaxDate = (select max(SnapshotDate) from [schemaname].[tablename])

    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake could achieve exactly the same behavior:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROC()
RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE SQL
AS 
DECLARE 
   MaxDate DATE;
BEGIN
    IF (NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                    from schema.table_name 
                    where SnapshotDate = current_date())) THEN
          MaxDate := (select max(SnapshotDate) from schemaname.tablename);
    END IF;

    RETURN MaxDate;
END
```